ng build takes forever and never finishes building
I'm new to Angular, and I am neither an expert on NodeJS nor Webpack. I built an app with Angular but when I try to deploy it, ng build doesn't seem to be working. The terminal says Building ... and looks like running but does nothing. I tried many times and waited for long, but it keeps the same: no error, and no other message than Building ... , until I decide to cancel. Of course, no dist folder.
These are my current settings:
Angular CLI: 17.3.7
Node: 22.2.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 6.14.9
OS: win32 x64

I noticed the Node version says unsupported, and I don't know whether it might be the cause of the issue. Actually I just upgraded Node from v21 to v22 before starting experiencing these issue, so chances are it's related. That's why I tried to downgrade to v21 again, but I'm having issues with nvm and can't (I can explain more in detail if you think the node version might be the cause). Node installer didn't work either, some prompt arguing that I have a newer node version and that the installation would cancel.
I also generated a clean test app to try and debug what might be the issue, and the result is the same (so it looks like the issue is not related to my "real-world" app). For what is worth, this is the new and clean app's package.json (which is probably just boilerplate):
{
  "name": "build-test-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/jmlinares2019/angular-deploy-test",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "serve:ssr:build-test-app": "node dist/build-test-app/server/server.mjs"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/ssr": "^17.3.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.18.0",
    "gh-pages": "^6.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.4.2"
  }
}

And here, the angular.json:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "build-test-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/build-test-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "server": "src/main.server.ts",
            "prerender": true,
            "ssr": {
              "entry": "server.ts"
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "build-test-app:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "build-test-app:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "build-test-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

As I said, I'm quite new to Angular and don't really understand much of this last file.
Any ideas? Is there any other info you need?
Thanks.
P.S.: in case you're wondering, ng serve works just fine. The problem is only with ng build.
UPDATE: As suggested by one of the answers, it looks like Angular doesn't support Node v22. I downgraded to Node v20. Now I'm facing other issues (supposedly not related with Node's version), but that one seems gone, as far as I understand.

In v17, if an app build never finishes it is most likely related to prerendering.
For your app to pre-render correctly, It need to become stable (see applicationRef.stable. It is most likely that you have a pending setTimeout/setInterval/Promise. Check for it.
Also note, that this issue is more visible in v18, as the CLI will throw if a component takes more than 30s to pre-render.

Thanks for your quick answer! However, what do you mean by "I need to become stable"? Probably a typo? Could you elaborate a little on the issue or could you provide me with some instructions, please? Thanks a lot!

https://angular.dev/api/core/ApplicationRef#isStable

Hi again. Thanks, I took a look, but I don't have any idea what I should do about it. As I said, I'm quite new to Angular, and I never came across with that concept. I've searched for occurrences of ApplicationRef in my code, but there's none. What should I do, please?

listen to that observable in your AppComponent. You'll see that it never returns true. This means something is preventing your app from going stable. The mains culprits are mentionned in my answer.

I'm trying to figure out what I should do, but I don't have any clue. It would be great to know how to listen to that ApplicationRef observable or what is preventing my app from going stable.
I have no idea about these things. My app is really simple and I never dealt with such complicated stuff. I'm new to Angular, and considering how complicated things look, and how docs seem written for already seasoned people, I'm reconsidering the chioce. It's kinda frustrating.

@MatthieuRiegler You were spot on. I had the same issue in v18. By just commenting a zone.run (to test) it completed the build quickly. This is bad, really, I mean, they should leave some comments / warnings or something.. Anyway, thanks.

There is bug with NodeJs 22.2. For more info check this issue https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/27674 You should downgrade Nodejs.

Yes! I just found out yesterday. It looks like Angular doesn't support Node v22. So I downgraded to Node v20. Now I'm facing other issues, but that one seems gone, as far as I understand. Thanks.

Hey I also faced the same issue , I rectified i was using async ngOnInit this makes your rendering process wait until they get a callback so build time never ends, remove any components with async ngOnInit and oyur issue will be resolved.
